# What is the purpose of continuous and differentiable dependence

Tags: soft-question, terminology, self-learning, intuition, functional-inequalities

In learning Gronwall's inequality you also get to learn about continuous an differentiable dependence. I know the theorems but I have no idea about their application.

What is the big idea of dependence? In what setting do you need to prove continuous or differentiable dependence?